# Node child_process.spawn: determine when all the spawned child processes are closed or have exited?

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

Is there a way to determine when the **all** spawned child processes are closed or have exited?

For example, how can I determine that there are no more processes to run, or in other words, all of 500 my child processes have exited?

```
for (let index = 0; index < 500; index++) {
  wkhtmltopdf = spawn('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf', ['--margin-left', '0', `${index}.html`, `${index}.pdf`])

  wkhtmltopdf.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`)
  })

  wkhtmltopdf.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`)
  })

  wkhtmltopdf.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is keep a counter and decrement it whenever a child process terminates.

```
var num_proc = 500;
var counter = num_proc;

for (let index = 0; index < num_proc; index++) {
  wkhtmltopdf = spawn('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf', 
                      ['--margin-left', '0', `${index}.html`, `${index}.pdf`]);

  wkhtmltopdf.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`)
  })

  wkhtmltopdf.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`)
  })

  wkhtmltopdf.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process stdio terminated with code ${code}`)
  })

  wkhtmltopdf.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`)
    counter--;

    if (counter <= 0) {
      console.log('everything finished')
    }
  })
}
```

I would use the [exit event](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit) to decrement the counter (instead of `close`) since `exit` is triggered on process termination while `close` triggers when the stdio stream has closed.